# PHP file Upload from Remote Service

Tags: c#, php, api, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following PHP code to receive a call from a remote service, decode the base64 string to the image and upload it to a local folder and return the name of the uploaded file with the extension.

```
public function UploadSurveyImageApi()
{
    try {
        $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($request_body, true);
       
        log_message("info", "I got into the survey image upload method");
        $response = ['filename' => '', 'status' => false, 'message' => 'Unknown error'];
        // Check if the request method is POST
       
            $parameters = $_REQUEST;
            log_message("info", "parameters is : " . print_r($parameters, 1));
            //$data = json_decode($parameters['image']);   

            // Get the Base64 encoded image string from the POST request body
            $base64_string = $data['image_base64string'];
            $filename = $data['filename'];
            $directory = !empty($data['upload_directory']) ? $data['upload_directory'] : 'uploads/survey';

            // Store the image and get the filename
            $uploaded_filename = $this->UploadSurveyImage($base64_string, $filename, $directory);
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['filename'] = $uploaded_filename;
            $response['message'] = "File successfully uploaded";
        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    } finally {
        // Return a JSON response with the filename
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }
}

public function UploadSurveyImage($base64_string, $filename, $directory = "uploads/survey")
{
    log_message("info","I got into the upload survey image method");
    // Decode the Base64 string to binary data
    $image_data = base64_decode($base64_string);

    // Create a new finfo resource
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    // Get the MIME type of the binary data
    $mime_type = finfo_buffer($finfo, $image_data);

    // Determine the file extension based on the MIME type

    $extension = image_type_to_extension($this->image_type_from_mime_type($mime_type));

    // Generate a unique filename for the image
    $filename = $filename . $extension;

    // Store the image in the directory
    $filepath = $directory . '/' . $filename;
    //return $filepath;
    //log_message('info','The file path for upload is '.$filepath);
    file_put_contents($filepath, $image_data);

    // Clean up
    finfo_close($finfo);

    // Return the filename of the image stored
    return $filename;
}


private function image_type_from_mime_type($mime_type)
{
    $mime_types = array(
        'image/jpeg' => IMAGETYPE_JPEG,
        'image/png' => IMAGETYPE_PNG,
        'image/gif' => IMAGETYPE_GIF,
        'image/webp' => IMAGETYPE_WEBP,
        // Add more MIME types and corresponding image types here
    );
    return isset($mime_types[$mime_type]) ? $mime_types[$mime_type] : 2;
}
```

The following is the dotnet code that calls the endpoint from remote server to upload the image

```
string fileUploadEndpoint = _appSettings.RemoteImageUploadEndpoint;
 var images = new List<string>();

var imageName = $"random-image-name-string";

// create an instance of HttpClient
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
 var requestContent = new ImageUploadApiRequestModel
 {
   ImageBase64String = image,
   Filename = imageName
 };

                          
 string requestBody = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestContent);

 // send the request and wait for the response
 var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(fileUploadEndpoint, new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

 // read the response body as a string
 var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 //var filePath = filedir+imageName;
 var responseData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ImageUploadApiResponseModel>(responseBody);
                            
 images.Add(responseData.UploadedFileName);
}
```

When I call the PHP endpoint from postman whether it is on my local machine or on the remote server, it works as expected and the image is uploaded.

Also, when I call the PHP endpoint on my local machine from the dotnet service, it also works as expected.
But when I upload the same PHP endpoint to a remote server and call it from dotner service, the image name does not return the file name . It only returns the extension (e.g. .jpeg instead of 'randome-filename.jpeg');

Is there something I am missing that stops the PHP endpoint at the remote server from working as expected when called from a dotnet service?

I will appreciate any guide to resolving this.

Thank you

Comment: Add some more logging between different steps and dump what the variables/methods you're using contains/returns to see where it fails. It's pretty hard to know where it fails since you say that it works on some servers and not others. We have no idea what the difference is between your different environments. We don't even know what the payload you're sending to the server actually looks like, since it seems to be abstracted away in your `ImageUploadApiRequestModel`.

Comment: Your code isn't really performing any validation of the input provided, and especially for an API I'd recommend you add that. If all you are getting back is an extension, that probably means that `$filename` is empty or null or similar at some point.